# Amen in Boneh Yerushalayim

Tags: tefilla, food, bentching, amen

In Birkat HaMazon, the one who is saying Birkat HaMazon answers amen to his own bracha during the third bracha, Boneh Yerushalayim, as required by the text.

1. Why is it that here we say amen to our own bracha? If it is because it is the end of a "group of brachot" why would we not say amen to our own brachot in other instances, for example the 19th bracha in Shmoneh Esrei?
2. If someone is listening to the one saying Birkat HaMazon, when would her or she answer amen to the bracha of Boneh Yerushalayim; would it be before or after the one saying it says his own amen?

Comment: Re 2: I don't understand why you would wait for them to say Amen. Can you clarify why you are unsure about the rule there?

Comment: Who's "we"? Some people do say Amen after the 19th bracha of shmone esrei

Comment: I apologize. Nusach Ashkenaz does not answer amen after the 19th bracha. I was not aware that there were people who did. I am unsure about the rule because the bracha has amen in it. So when would the person answering amen at the end of the bracha do it?

Comment: I suppose it would be wise to separate the two questions, and focus on one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

1) The Shulchan Aruch and the Rema both hold that  we say Amen at the end the third bracha of the Birkhat HaMazon ("Boneh Yerushalayim") because that point is the end of the d'oraita Birkhat HaMazon, and the entire fourth bracha is mi derabanan. Nusach Sephardi / Edot HaMizrach is stringent to say amen softly so as not to lessen the importance of the fourth bracha, Ashkenazim are generally lenient in this regard. B'eH Bli nader I will post the exact siman and perek tomorrow.

2) someome hearing the Birkhat HaMazon and not saying it for himself would say amen after the one saying it reflecting the former custom of one person saying the bracha for the table and everyone else being exempted

Comment: Your answer doesn't respond to question 1/b, namely why don't most do this on other instances.

Comment: That's a very good question on its own, @Kazi. We say it here and in "Oseh Shalom" and at the end of Kaddish and even there it's "vimru amen"

Comment: BTW, start here: https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.45b.22?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en